# Can only edit longer pages on phone, not on PC

Tags: editor

I have written and edited many longer WP blog pages on a phone. But when I now try to edit them on a PC, the editor freezes or gives extremely long latencies (>10 sec.) between key press and effect. I use the classic editor in text mode. I recently bought a laptop with "gaming specs" but the problem persists. I have tried Chrome or Edge browsers. On phone I edit straight off the web page, like the PC, I do not use the WP app.

I have tried putting Google Chrome in developer/phone mode which has maybe helped occasionally but not consistently. (developer functions drain computer power?)

I can only edit long pages on the phone but not on the PC. Please advise what to do.

Comment: strange, what's your editor name?

Comment: I use a plug in called classic editor which gives me the editor I am used to. I always use text mode and not "visual". I believe that should not consume much computer resources. I mostly just use text, links, images and very simple things. So I just edit text in a web form and press update.